# Changing property 'OptimizeModelRefInitCode' is not allowed

Tags: matlab, simulink

So I have a Simulink model with another model referenced (because it's too big). Upon compiling (with Real-Tome Workshop) I want to optimize initialization code. But this is refused for all my models. I use :

set_param(gcs, 'OptimizeModelRefInitCode', 'on')

And I get the error in the title. Any idea why that is ? Can anyone point me in the right direction ? I'll give more details wen asked.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT :  I have tested it and realized it was the case with any new model I create under Simulink.

EDIT 2 : I opened my models as text files and changed the setting manually to 'on'. Simulink or Matlab never complained. Now I can't tell wether the targets were built with the setting ... But I may have bypassed a check (that was giving me the error) and created other problems elsewhere.

Comment: Can you provide the actual error you get?

Comment: The error is in the title :
Error using set_param :
Changing property 'OptimizeModelRefInitCode' is not allowed.

Comment: I have a similar problem when changing the Block Reduction property: `set_param('pf_mon_mac','BlockReduction','off')`
`Changing property 'BlockReduction' is not allowed`